Ethernet & USB Dongle not working
My machine running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS is unable to connect to the internet. The ethernet and Wirless dongle do not appear as options in the settings and I'm unsure on how to fix this
The wireless dongle is a TP-Link AC1300
Browsed heavily through other posts and nothing seems to work
Here's some information which I've seen requested in other posts
lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3:
22:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7b86]
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] [10de:1c02] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] [1043:85b9]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

lshw -C network:
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff

ifconfig -a doesn't show the Wireless dongle or Ethernet
I was attempting to install the Realtek drivers while offline but after follwing the README file I get this when trying to run their Shell script:
sudo ./autorun.sh:
Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
make: C: No such file or directory
make: [Makefile:48: clean] Error 127 (ignored)
make: C: No such file or directory
make: [Makefile:41: modules] Error 127 (ignored)
make: C: No such file or directory
make: [Makefile:55: install] Error 127 (ignored)
ls: cannot access 'src/*.ko': No such file or directory
No driver exists!!!

sudo lshw - C network:
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff

I've also seen this post which has a solution which I want to try but I'm unsure how to modify the solution for my Realtek devices
Please let me know if you need further information and thanks in advance
EDIT:
sudo modprobe r8168; sudo dmesg | grep -i r816:
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8168 not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-35-generic

ls -l /lib/media/6.5.0-35-generic:
total 1624
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May 16 18:41 build
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May  6 16:02 initrd
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root   4096 May 15 09:33 kernel
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 158374 May 15 09:33 modules.alias
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 167700 May 15 09:33 modules.alias.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   9589 May  6 16:02 modules.builtin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  28801 May 15 09:33 modules.builtin.alias.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  11571 May 15 09:33 modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  84033 May  6 16:02 modules.builtin.modinfo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  89822 May 15 09:33 modules.dep
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 129701 May 15 09:33 modules.dep.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    291 May 15 09:33 modules.devname
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 258693 May  6 16:02 modules.order
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    455 May 15 09:33 modules.softdep
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 312925 May 15 09:33 modules.symbols
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 366367 May 15 09:33 modules.symbols.bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 May 15 09:33 vdso


Any results from terminal for sudo modprobe r8169; sudo dmesg|grep -i r816

@Jeremy31 I've added this to the post. I also added an ls into the dir as I was certain the module is within there!

Check dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)

@Jeremy31 That gave no output

Don't know if it's important, but in the /lib/module dir there is multiple generic modules:
6.5.0-18-generic
6.5.0-28-generic
6.5.0-35-generic

Sii if you can get grub advanced options menu at boot and see if it works with an kernel other than -35

@Jeremy31 Okay I pulled it back to 28 and it worked first time. Is there any advice for fixing the other kernel version?

While you are booted into a working kernel sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-35-generic then reboot and let it boot on its own

Awesome, it's back up and running in kernel version 35. I appreciate your time and patience!

Jeremy31 had the answers here
Looks like the kernel version was problematic (v35), most likely due to some updates which weren't properly completed before a crash happened
Restarted the machine and held down Shift to open the GRUB menu, go to advanced options and load an older Kernel version (v28 in my case)
Once loaded, everything was working. So I ran the following to repair the v35 Kernel:
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-35-generic

Once completed, restarted and all worked well!
